# How can I better optimize the following PHP code that gets user input and displays a predefined output?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to get the input from a user and display a text based on the input from the user. For example the user input 1, the browser should display One and if the user inputs 2 browser should display two. I have created a code for that but please can anyone guide me on how I can better optimise the code and use ajax. I would really appreciate if anyone could let me know how can I create this as a wordpress pluign as well. Thank you.

Code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Display quote of the day</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
    Please Enter a number between 1 to 70:<br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="quote-number">
    <input type="submit" value="Show Quote">
</form>
<?php
//Default values
$one = "Quote one";
$two = "Quote two";
$three = "Quote three";
$four = "Quote four";
$five = "Quote five";

//Saving the value in a variable
$number = isset($_POST['quote-number']);
if ($number) {
    $quotevalue = $_POST['quote-number'];
}

if ($quotevalue==1) {
    echo "$one";
} elseif ($quotevalue==2) {
    echo "$two";
} elseif ($quotevalue==3) {
    echo "$three";
} elseif ($quotevalue==4) {
    echo "$four";
} elseif ($quotevalue==5) {
    echo "$five";
} else {
    echo "<br /> Please enter a number from 1 to 70.";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use switch statements

```
switch (n) {
case label1:
    code to be executed if n=label1;
    break;
case label2:
    code to be executed if n=label2;
    break;
case label3:
    code to be executed if n=label3;
    break;
...
default:
    code to be executed if n is different from all labels;
```

}

more look here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp